# Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 3

Tags: objective-c, string, url, arguments

I am trying to get data from a JSON feed. The feed URL needs to be edited by my program so that it has the correct co-ordinates. But I keep on getting the error:

> Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 3

Here is my code:

```
NSString *lat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
latitude.text = lat;

NSString *lng = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
longitude.text = lng;

NSString *acc = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.horizontalAccuracy];
accuracy.text = acc;

//

NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.wunderground.com/api/595007cb79ada1b1/geolookup/q/%@,%@.json", lat, lng]];
```

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`URLWithString` is not expecting a format string, so does not expect the arguments `lng` and `lat`

Try creating that string elsewhere first using a constructor that takes a format string:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString  stringWithFormat: @"http://api.wunderground.com/api/595007cb79ada1b1/geolookup/q/%@,%@.json", lat, lng];
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code and for your explanation of what was wrong. Very helpful indeed :)